# Mysql_result - выводит только первый символ

Tags: php, mysql

Почему выводит только первую букву записанного в него слова? Разве mysql_result не всю ячейку передает?

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("t_db_06_11");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT des FROM foto3 WHERE id='3'");
$row = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo ("<img src='../img/$row[des].jpg'>");
```

Comment: @mkrichet1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

А вы [доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php) читали? В row строка, а вы как с массивом работаете

**UPD:** да и вообще, если что-то возвращает не то, что надо, попробуйте вывести это полностью. Что мешало сделать `var_dump($row)`? Сразу бы увидели что не так.